# Argument of type 'Date | null' is not assignable to parameter

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to add a new field in the filter, there was no problem with this when the type was string or number but I have a problem with a field of type **Date**.

**UPDATE**:

```
private updateParameters(query: string): void {
    const filterParameters = new HttpParams({
        fromString: query
    });
    this.filters.date = (filters.date && filters.date[0] !== null && filters.date[1] !== null) ? [timeZone(filterParameters.get('startDate')), timeZone(filterParameters.get('endDate'))] : [];
}
```

And in such code I get errors:

**Argument of type 'Date | null' is not assignable to parameter of type string**

**Type 'Date | null' is not assignable to type 'Date'**

And I don't know how I can solve this anymore, because TypeScript is very diligent about types here.

Comment: The issue is probably that in theory, `timeZone(filterParameters.get('startDate'))` could return a `Date`, `timeZone(filterParameters.get('endDate'))` could return a `null`, then the type of `this.filters.date` would be `[Date, null]`, which you've said isn't allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `function timeZoneStartDate(date: Date) : string;` that accepts `Date`, but `this.filters.date[0]` and `this.filters.date[1]` can both be `Date | null` (because you declared `date?: [Date, Date] | [null, null]`).
`Date | null` can't be casted as `Date`, causing the error.

In this case you could use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) to handle the case where they are null and tell typescript that, when you are using the function, they are only of type `Date`. The simplest guard you can use is `if (this.filters.date[0] !== null)`

```
if (filters.date && filters.date[0] !== null && filters.date[1] !== null) {
  parameters = addToQuery(parameters, 'startDate', timeZoneStartDate(filters.date[0]));
  parameters = addToQuery(parameters, 'endDate', timeZoneEndDate(filters.date[1]));
}
```

You can see an example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=2&pln=13&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgMQQBtUoBnOAbwCglMBbYAfgC44yYpkBzOAHzhIArkSIBuamEzdgAOSH0ARmlaCFyqBIAmmVKoDaAEV3AANHGOoAuvzj7ho8w6JWJAX2rYISDnHTFSMjZCEjQKAF4qD09vX0wtLQAVCABFITQATzhIgAopKAZgQLYOLiRucwBrYAySzh5zADdMInS2TCQMgEo6st5wgD44ACJhiS8feBgERgAtb2AAZRhMWEs8XJ1UNnWe9nry7KHR8dipmeB5pGAAUSQtdey4HK3gHZM90p4jkbHqaiIRTg%20UKxX2fSeJ2oCHQz38oXIADpXnAAGSovwBMLIkz6AAMNgAhOFIs40Rj4YEcah9ABGIkktSiLpUahwYGrUFhJ7xJKpdJQDJ5TmMQLmADkHFWMHW4vM0zmC2W0vWOUp2Ne%20KsXS6EnZINF3MivOSaUywoKhvIEuA91l8ouV1udpMaqxSM19J17iAA).

**Edit**
`this.filters` becomes:

```
this.filters.date = (filterParameters.get('startDate') !== null && filterParameters.get('endDate') !== null ) ? [ timeZone(filterParameters.get('startDate')), timeZone(filterParameters.get('endDate'))] : [];
```

I'm using the same if with a ternary operator, but you can make the code more readable now that you have the concept.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Adding an if in the `getFilters` function helped, but the problem still occurs in the `updateParameters` function which is this code: ```this.filters.date = [
timeZone(filterParameters.get('startDate')),
timeZone(filterParameters.get('endDate'))];```
How can this be solved?

Comment: I have updated the code with the changes. Unfortunately, the same error still occurs in line `this.filters.date`

Comment: Please, show more information about `this.filters.date` and `filterParameters`, they are not in the question and I can only try guessing!

Comment: I saw there was a typo in my answer, I have updated the line of code, maybe now it works... Let me know!